# Include not working in LINQ query but works in LINQ Fluent API

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-2.1

**The Problem**

I have a LINQ query (against Entity Framework) that use `Include` to include some navigation properties.  One of those properties uses `ThenInclude` to include its own property collection.  When I run the query, the first level properties are included on the primary object but the sub-collection (the one using ThenInclude) is always empty.

However, if I change the query to use Fluent API form, the query works and the sub-collection is actually included.  Why does this work for the Fluent form and not the normal LINQ query?

**Example**

```
//FAIL - This returns Benefits but Benefits.Dates.Count = 0 on all Benefits
var list1 = (from s in _context.Subscribers
               .Include(s => s.Dates)
               .Include(s => s.Benefits)
               .ThenInclude(b => b.Dates)
               where s.Id == 13643
               select new { benefits = s.Benefits }).ToList();

//SUCCESS - This returns Benefits and Benefits.Dates.Count is > 0 on the ones with Dates
var list2 = _context.Subscribers
               .Include(s => s.Dates)
               .Include(s => s.Benefits)
               .ThenInclude(b => b.Dates)
               .Where(s => s.Id == 13643)
               .Select(s => new { benefits = s.Benefits}).ToList();
```

Am I mistaken that these queries should give the same output?

**Update**

I just tried manually linking things using LINQ and I am able to get Benefit dates included -- granted, its not apples to apples as the resulting set is different, but the point is that `Include(b => b.Dates)` seems to work in this case.

```
var list3 = (from s in _context.Subscribers.Include(s => s.Dates)
             join b in _context.Benefits.Include(b => b.Dates) on s.Id equals b.SubscriberId
             select new {benefits = b}).ToList();
```

I'm beginning to wonder if `ThenInclude()` may be a little more restrictive in where/when it can be used?

**Update 2**

I just noticed a warning in my Debug Output window that led me to [this link about ignored includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#ignored-includes).  This seems to be on the right track as the Debug Output clearly indicates that these includes are being ignored.

What doesn't make sense, though, is that I'm actually selecting to anonymous in both examples and only one of them seems to ignore the includes.  Why one and not the other?

Comment: Most likely a bug, but just wondering, why are you selecting an anonymous object instead of just `s => s.Benefits`? Also, the first `Include` for `Dates` is omitted as it is not used. You could have just used `_context.Benefits.Include(x => x.Dates).Where(x => x.SubscriberId == 13643).ToList()`

Comment: So the query I'm after is much more complex but when it wasn't working, I started simplifying it down to just the pieces that needed to be included.  So, while I'm not using `Subscriber.Dates` at this point in time, I will be using it once I get this simplistic model resolved.  (The same goes for the selecting to anonymous -- not necessary in my example, but will be necessary in the final query)

Comment: Something to keep in mind when writing complex queries using EF, is perforamce... EF converts your linq query to SQL, but it may not be as efficient as your own SQL. Personally I would not use LINQ to SQL for writing complex queries... you could potentially write more efficient SQL. See point #3 [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Entity+Framework/141158/)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess: since You have `Datas`, in both `Subscribers` and `Benefits`, there is a chance that you are not querying the correct model/entity... you can try confirming the entity type like below (assuming `Benefit` is your Entity type).

```
var list1 = (from s in _context.Subscribers
               .Include(s => s.Dates)
               .Include(s => s.Benefits)
               .ThenInclude(b => (b as Benefit).Dates)
               where s.Id == 13643
               select new { benefits = s.Benefits }).ToList();

var list2 = _context.Subscribers
           .Include(s => s.Dates)
           .Include(s => s.Benefits)
           .ThenInclude(b => (b as Benefit).Dates) // <-- I suggest renaming s to b
           .Where(s => s.Id == 13643)
           .Select(s => new { benefits = s.Benefits}).ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry, I actually did use `b` in my code rather than `s` -- I've updated my code to reflect that change.  I'll trying the cast and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Casting `(b as Benefit)` did not help.  I also tried removing `.Include(s => s.Dates)` (subscriber dates), and that didn't help either.  Benefits still get returned with no Dates.

Comment: Casting help me in a similar case.